# Modal dialog doesn't show up

Tags: javascript, php, html, modal-dialog

I were changing some PHP-Script that you can't delete protected users from a datatable and now for some reason the modal which shows the warning "Are you sure to delete...?" doesn't show up anymore BUT the background gets dark and you can't interact with the page anymore (even if the selected user isn't protected)

I analyzed the code and haven't seen any issues (I am a amateur only knowing school IT)

HTML-Code

```html
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="modal_delete">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form method="post" ng-submit="submitForm()">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">{{modalTitle}}</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <h5>Sind Sie sich sicher diesen Benutzer unwiderruflich zu löschen?</h5>
                    <p ng-class="customStyle.colorClass">{{successMessage}}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <input type="hidden" name="hidden_id" value="{{hidden_id}}" />
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Ja, ich bin mir sicher!"/>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Schließen</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

AngularJS (JavaScript) Code

```
$scope.openModalDelete = function(){
        var modal_popup = $("#modal_delete");
        modal_popup.modal('show');
        $scope.deleteMessage();
    }

$scope.closeModalDelete = function(){
        var modal_popup = $('#modal_delete');
        modal_popup.modal('hide');
    }

$scope.submitForm = function(){
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '../ajax/benutzer_insertData.php',
            data: {
                'isAdmin': $scope.isAdmin,
                'password': $scope.password,
                'passwordValidate': $scope.passwordValidate,
                'id': $scope.currentId, 
                'first_name': $scope.first_name, 
                'last_name': $scope.last_name, 
                'email': $scope.email, 
                'action': $scope.submit_button}
        }).then(function successCallback(response){
            $scope.turnColor(response.data.color);
            $scope.stateSet = $scope.state;
            $scope.success = true;
            $scope.error = false;
            $scope.successMessage = response.data.successMsg;
            $scope.errFirstName = response.data.firstNameError;
            $scope.errLastName = response.data.lastNameError;
            $scope.errEMail = response.data.eMailError;
            $scope.errPassword = response.data.passwordError;
            $scope.form_data = {};
            $scope.getData();
        });
    }

$scope.deleteData = function(id){
        $scope.modalTitle = "Benutzer löschen";
        $scope.submit_button = "Löschen";
        $scope.currentId = id;
        $scope.openModalDelete();
    }
```

PHP-Code

```php
if($request->action == 'Löschen'){
            $sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id = ".$id." AND protected = 0";
            $statement = $con->prepare($sql);
            $statement->execute();
            $successMsg = "Benutzer wurde erfolgreich gelöscht";
            $color = "green";
        }
```

There are no things like Error-Messages and the console is completly fine

Comment: you're open to SQL injection and should resolve imminently